# Error $injector:unpr when i'm triying to inject a server AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use some global functions from a certain file, and call 'em from a different .js files. The file where the functions lives is called `header.js`:

```
(function(){

var head = {
    templateUrl: '/app/components/include/header.html',
    controller: headCtrl
};

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .component('adminHead', head);
    headCtrl.$inject = ["$http"];
    function headCtrl($http){

        function test() {
            console.log('working');
            }                  

        }

    })();
```

And i need to call the example function on the `home.js` file:

```
    (function(){
    'use strict';

    var home = {
        templateUrl: '/app/components/home/admin-home.html',
        controller: adminHomeCtrl
    };

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .component('adminHome', home);
        adminHomeCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$cookies"];
        function adminHomeCtrl($scope, $http, $cookies){


        }
})();
```

Previously, someone hre on Stackoverflow help me with an example of a service to call those global functions. So, i've created a new file called `excelsior.js` an save the example:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('MyService', ['myDependency', function (myDependency) {
      const s = {
        test: function() {
          console.log('working');
        },
      };
      return s;
    }]);
})();
```

Now my problem comes when i'm triying to inject 'MyService' as a dependency. I've put on both files the dependency like this:

```
    (function(){
    'use strict';

    var home = {
        templateUrl: '/app/components/home/admin-home.html',
        controller: adminHomeCtrl
    };

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .component('adminHome', home);
        adminHomeCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$cookies", "MyService"];
        function adminHomeCtrl($scope, $http, $cookies, MyService){


            var x = MyService.test();
            console.log(x);

        }
})();
```

But now i'm getting the next error message:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/unpr?p0=myDependencyProvider%20%3C-%20myDependency%20%3C-%20MyService
```

Somene knows why is happening? On other post, i've found that i also have to declare it on my app.js, and i did it like this:

```
    (function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'MyService']);

})();
```

But it gets worst, 'cause my app crashes with the next message:

```
angular.js:88 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=adminApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.9%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DMyService%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.9%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DMyService%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A76%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A408%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A439)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A182%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A332%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A180)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A364%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A76%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A99%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A364%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A250)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)
```

There's something missing? Or why is not working when i'm injecting the dependency?

On my index.html i've called the js like this:

```
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/login/admin-login.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/include/excelsior.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/include/header.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/home/admin-home.js"></script>
```

Even, i've tried changing the order of th files, putting the excelsior file after admin-home file, but still the same error.

I'm working with AngularJs and Javascript.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you don't want to inject `MyService` in your main `myApp` module, because you are registering the service in `myApp` using `angular.module('myapp').factory('MyService', [...])`. Second, the injection error you are getting is for `myDependency` into your `MyService` service. Where is `myDependency` coming from?

Comment: Now i got it! I've asked for an example of service, 'cause i'm new using it. And the example that received have `myDependency`. I've removed `myDependency` and it works! Thank you.